# do these two groups isomorphic to each other?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

consider two groups $T=<x,y |x^4=y^3=1,yxy=x>$ and $A=<x,y |x^6=1,x^3=y^2,xy=yx^{-1}>$, are these two groups isomorphic?

I think this is not true,because $T$ don't have any 4 member cyclic subgroups but $A$ has $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ as a cyclic subgroups.

so if they are not isomorphism then can you tell me what group $A$ is isomorphic to within 12 elements nonabelian groups? thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ is the semidirect product of $C_3$ by $C_4$ by the map $g : C_4 \rightarrow Aut(C_3)$ given by $g(k) = a^k$, where $a$ is the automorphism $a(x) = -x$. It is indeed isomorphic to $A$. So, $A\simeq T$ are isomorphic nonabelian groups of order $12$. Altogether there are three different nonabelian groups of order $12$, namely $D_6$, $A_4$ and $T$.

Comment: why checking their subgroups as I did, give wrong result?

Comment: my mistake!!both have it!

Comment: yes,you are right, thanks for your good answer!