# For a group $G$, $N\unlhd G$, $G/N\cong\Bbb{Z}/a\Bbb{Z}$ and $N\cong\Bbb{Z}/b\Bbb{Z}$, where $b<a$ and $(b,a)=1$, show $G$ is abelian.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

I've been pounding my head on my desk attempting to figure out how to start this proof:

> If we have a group $G$, a normal subgroup $N\trianglelefteq G$, $G/N \cong \mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$, and $N \cong \mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$, where $b<a$, and $(b,a) = 1$, how can we show that $G$ is an abelian group?

I'm stuck on how to start this proof. I know the fact that $b$ and $a$ are relatively prime will have something to do with the proof. Hints as to how to approach this are greatly appreciated (but please do not post the entire proof, or at the bare minimum please hide it in spoiler tags).

Comment: Hint: How many homomorphism are there between $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: In the general case (a,b are not relatively prime) that would be $|H| = gcd(a,b)$, which in this case is 1 because they're relatively prime.

Comment: That's correct! What does this say about your groups?

Comment: @SebastianCor:  Why would you be looking at that, though? $G/N$ acts on $N$, which means you have a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin As per requested I'm not posting the main idea of the proof until OP determines he wants it. Also I can't seem to use spoilers in comments.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin what do you mean by $G/N$ "acts on" $N$? I'm not familiar with that phrasing.

Comment: @SebastianCor does that mean that the homomorphism is the identity homomorphism (e.g, $h:G\Rightarrow G = h(x) = e$?)

Comment: If you consider what happens when you conjugate by elements of $G$, because $N$ is normal, each element of $G$ will transform the elements of $N$ like an automorphism of $N$. Because $N$ is abelian, the elements of $N$ don't actually do anything, so you get a map from $G/N$ to $\mathrm{Aut}(N)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128288/discussion-between-sebastian-cor-and-arturo-magidin).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this statement is true.

Consider the [dicyclic group of order $12$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3180033/what-is-the-dicyclic-group-of-order-12-what-is-mathbbz-3-rtimes-mathbb): this is the nontrivial semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ (so $b=3$, $a=4$; thus $b\lt a$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$), with the nontrivial action of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Explicitly: denote the generator of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ by $x$, and the generator of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ by $y$. The group $$\langle x\mid x^3=1\rangle \rtimes \langle y\mid y^4=1\rangle$$
has underlying set $\langle x\rangle \times \langle y\rangle$. The action is given by ${}^yx = x^{-1}$. Thus, the elements have the form $x^ry^s$ with $0\leq r\lt 3$, $0\leq s\lt 4$, and product given by
$$(x^ry^s)(x^{\rho}y^{\sigma}) = x^{r+(-1)^s\rho}y^{s+\sigma}.$$
The subgroup generated by $x$ is cyclic of order $3$ and normal. The quotient is generated by $y$ and thus cyclic, of order $4$ since $G$ has order $12$ and $\langle x\rangle$ has order $3$.  And the group is nonabelian, since $x^{-1}\neq x$, yet $yx = x^{-1}y$.

In the notation of the problem: $G=C_3\rtimes C_4$. $N=\langle x\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$; $G/N\cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. We have $3\lt 4$ and $\gcd(3,4)=1$.

---

[More on groups of order $12$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_12); groupswiki is not necessarily always reliable, but this is simple enough that it is unlikely to contain errors. [Here's Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicyclic_group?wprov=sfti1). Note that Wikipedia is realizing the group as an extension of $C_6$ by $C_2$; but the subgroup of order $3$ in $C_6$ is characteristic, hence invariant under the action. If you take the presentation
$$\langle a,x\mid a^{6}=1, x^2=a^3, xax^{-1}=a^{-1}\rangle$$
then the subgroup generated by $a^2$ is normal of order $3$, and the quotient is generated by $x$ (using $x^2=a^3$) and thus is cyclic of order $4$.

---

More generally, if $N$ is nontrivial cyclic of odd order $2n+1$, then inversion is an automorphism of order $2$. If we take any cyclic group of order $2^k$, this group can be made to act on $N$ by inversion, defining a nontrivial semidirect product $C_{2n+1}\rtimes C_{2^k}$. This is nonabelian because the action is nontrivial and $2n+1\gt 1$; it has a normal subgroup of order $2n+1$ and the quotient is cyclic of order $2^k$, with $\gcd(2n+1,2^k)=1$. Make $k$ sufficiently large so that $2n+1\lt 2^k$ and you have other similar examples.

Comment: Interesting... so the generalization I tried to make did not work. I was trying to generalize the problem of $N\cong Z/2Z$, and $G/N = Z/5Z$.

Comment: @blackbrandt: If you were attempting a statement that you were conjecturing, it would really be best to **tell** people that it was your conjecture. The way you posted, it looks more like an exercise/theorem you encountered and you are trying to prove it. Which was it?

Comment: @blackbrandt: Since the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial, the action of $G/N$ on $N$ is trivial. Normal subgroups of order $2$ are always central, so everything commutes with all their elements. If $G/N$ is cyclic, then a pullback of the generator together with the nontrivial element of $N$ generates $G$, and the two commute, so $G$ is abelian (though not necessarily cyclic; however, in *that* case $G$ will in fact be cyclic).

Comment: I'm realizing that in hindsight... I was hoping that the generalization would help me understand the problem more but I didn't realize my generalization was not accurate. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: @blackbrandt: If you further assume that $G/N$ has odd order (when $N$ is cyclic of order $2$), then $G$ will necessarily be cyclic. It is abelian even if $G/N$ has even order, but in that case it need not be cyclic; e.g., $C_4$.